# How to close the pop up window of modal dialog?

Tags: javascript

I am using modal dialog to validate server credentials.
After clicking on submit button it  pops up new window.
Further i want call a servel. But its get called in the same pop up window.
I want to call it in the parent window by closing the pop up window.
How to achieve this?

Comment: please explain it in detail so than one could be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// opening new window
var myWindow = window.open(...);

// when you want to close it
myWindow.close();
```

If you want to close the popup window in JS executed on this new window's content it's even easier:

```
window.close()
```

Comment: This is for a 'modeless' window, but still a good answer as modal dialogues are deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog)